# Why VS2017 WPF Application Properties gives me error?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017

While I choose other project types this works as expected, if I choose any WPF app, application properties will give the below error.

[image]

All other tabs work as expected.

Tried cleaning manifest files, reinstalling but all have no effect.

On another PC, everything works as expected.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80670/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftvsdesigne-1.html  have you tried this?

Comment: I added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the solution from this link (The person who found the solution is Sebastien Lebreton): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80670/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftvsdesigne-1.html

Please do the following to fix your issue:

- Quit VS 2017
- Launch VS 2017 Installer.
- Click Modify.
- Check the ".NET desktop development" workload.
- Click Modify.
- Reload your project

This should solve your issue.

Regards

**Sebastien Lebreton** [MSFT]